# How to reset dropdown on primefaces commandButton reset type

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

How to reset the value of p:selectOneMenu on pressing p:commandButton on type reset. The code i have is as follows

```
<h:form id="form">

    <p:panelGrid columns="2" cellspacing="10" >
    <f:facet name="header">Login</f:facet>
    <p:outputLabel value="Username" />
    <p:inputText value="#{user.username}" />
    <p:outputLabel value="Password" />
    <p:password value="#{user.password}"></p:password>

    <p:outputLabel value="Locale" />
    <p:selectOneMenu >
    <f:selectItem itemValue="Select Country" itemLabel="Select Country" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="Poland" itemLabel="Poland"/>
    </p:selectOneMenu>
    <p:commandButton value="Submit"></p:commandButton>
    <p:commandButton type="reset" value="Clear" update="form"></p:commandButton>
    </p:panelGrid>

</h:form>
```

On doing so, the username and password get cleared but  the dropdown for select country is not reset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you are just showing the values in your `p:selectOneMenu` but not assigning those values, `value` property stands to be able to assign currently selected value from client side into the backing bean value, so;

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="myMenu" value="#{bean.selectedCountry}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="Select Country" itemLabel="Select Country" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="Poland" itemLabel="Poland"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Now if user selects Poland as country it will be setted as `selectedCountry` on the backing bean also do not forget to implement getter and setter methods.

Then if you want to reset the value of the component, `p:selectOneMenu` generates a label and changing it's text can do the trick on view:

```
<p:commandButton onclick="resetter();" type="reset" value="Clear" update="form"></p:commandButton>
```

And the js function:

```
function resetter() {
    document.getElementById('form:myMenu_label').innerHTML = 'Select Country';
}
```